# Match rows in one Pandas dataframe to another based on three columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two Pandas dataframes, one quite large (30000+ rows) and one a lot smaller (100+ rows).

The dfA looks something like:

```
      X     Y    ONSET_TIME    COLOUR 
0   104    78          1083         6    
1   172    78          1083        16
2   240    78          1083        15 
3   308    78          1083         8
4   376    78          1083         8
5   444    78          1083        14
6   512    78          1083        14
... ...   ...           ...       ...
```

The dfB looks something like:

```
    TIME     X     Y
0      7   512   350 
1   1722   512   214 
2   1906   376   214 
3   2095   376   146 
4   2234   308    78 
5   2406   172   146
...  ...   ...   ...
```

What I want to do is for every row in dfB to find the row in dfA where the values of the X AND Y columns are equal AND that is the first row where the value of dfB['TIME'] is greater than dfA['ONSET_TIME'] and return the value of dfA['COLOUR'] for this row.

dfA represents refreshes of a display, where X and Y are coordinates of items on the display and so repeat themselves for every different ONSET_TIME (there are 108 pairs of coodinates for each value of ONSET_TIME).

There will be multiple rows where the X and Y in the two dataframes are equal, but I need the one that matches the time too.

I have done this using for loops and if statements just to see that it could be done, but obviously given the size of the dataframes this takes a very long time.

```
for s in range(0, len(dfA)):
    for r in range(0, len(dfB)):
        if (dfB.iloc[r,1] == dfA.iloc[s,0]) and (dfB.iloc[r,2] == dfA.iloc[s,1]) and (dfA.iloc[s,2] <= dfB.iloc[r,0] < dfA.iloc[s+108,2]):
            return dfA.iloc[s,3]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is probably an even more efficient way to do this, but here is a method without those slow for loops:

```
import pandas as pd

dfB = pd.DataFrame({'X':[1,2,3],'Y':[1,2,3], 'Time':[10,20,30]})
dfA = pd.DataFrame({'X':[1,1,2,2,2,3],'Y':[1,1,2,2,2,3], 'ONSET_TIME':[5,7,9,16,22,28],'COLOR': ['Red','Blue','Blue','red','Green','Orange']})

#create one single table
mergeDf = pd.merge(dfA, dfB, left_on = ['X','Y'], right_on = ['X','Y'])
#remove rows where time is less than onset time
filteredDf = mergeDf[mergeDf['ONSET_TIME'] < mergeDf['Time']]
#take min time (closest to onset time)
groupedDf = filteredDf.groupby(['X','Y']).max()

print filteredDf

 COLOR  ONSET_TIME  X  Y  Time
0     Red           5  1  1    10
1    Blue           7  1  1    10
2    Blue           9  2  2    20
3     red          16  2  2    20
5  Orange          28  3  3    30


print groupedDf

COLOR  ONSET_TIME  Time
X Y                          
1 1     Red           7    10
2 2     red          16    20
3 3  Orange          28    30
```

The basic idea is to merge the two tables so you have the times together in one table.  Then I filtered on the recs that are the largest (closest to the time on your dfB).  Let me know if you have questions about this.

Comment: That's really helpful thanks, although I found that your final groupedDf was missing some of the values from the original DfB. 

I tried: filteredDF.sort('ONSET_TIME').groupby(['DfB_INDEX'], as_index = False).max()

And that gives me that values I'm looking for as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 2):

Use `merge()` - it works like `JOIN` in SQL - and you have first part done.

```
d1 = '''      X     Y    ONSET_TIME    COLOUR 
   104    78          1083         6    
   172    78          1083        16
   240    78          1083        15 
   308    78          1083         8
   376    78          1083         8
   444    78          1083        14
   512    78          1083        14
   308    78          3000        14
   308    78          2000        14''' 


d2 = '''    TIME     X     Y
      7   512   350 
   1722   512   214 
   1906   376   214 
   2095   376   146 
   2234   308    78 
   2406   172   146'''

import pandas as pd
from StringIO import StringIO

dfA = pd.DataFrame.from_csv(StringIO(d1), sep='\s+', index_col=None)
#print dfA

dfB = pd.DataFrame.from_csv(StringIO(d2), sep='\s+', index_col=None)
#print dfB

df1 =  pd.merge(dfA, dfB, on=['X','Y'])
print df1
```

result:

```
     X   Y  ONSET_TIME  COLOUR  TIME
0  308  78        1083       8  2234
1  308  78        3000      14  2234
2  308  78        2000      14  2234
```

Then you can use it to filter results.

```
df2 = df1[ df1['ONSET_TIME'] < df1['TIME'] ]
print df2
```

result:

```
     X   Y  ONSET_TIME  COLOUR  TIME
0  308  78        1083       8  2234
2  308  78        2000      14  2234
```

Comment: he also wants the time to be greater than onset_time.  Add df = pd.merge(dfA, dfB, on=['X','Y']); df = df[df["ONSET_TIME"] >df["TIME"]]

Comment: Thanks, I made it in meanwhile :) I do it piece by piece - test it - and add to answer. This way I learn `pandas` :)