# How to get python to recognize "YYYY W##" as date time object and then fill add time objects less than a certain week

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, datetime, dataframe

I have a dataframe consisting of columns `Name` (names), `value` (the week in 2016 that an event occurred), `binary` (an indication that the event occurred, "1"), for example:

```
df 
    Name      value      binary
    apple     2016 W16   1
    orange    2016 W17   1
    melon     2016 W20   1
    berry     2016 W17   1
    lime      2016 W19   1
```

I am interested in adding rows to this dataframe so that each `Name` (apple, orange, etc.) has an item in the `value` column for the weeks *before* an event occurred. Again, the week that the event occurred is stated as the `value` column in `df`. The time period of interest is the weeks between 2016 W16 and 2016 W19, e.g.:

```
start_end_weeks
     week
     2016 W16
     2016 W17
     2016 W18
     2016 W19
```

My problem is that I need to in-fill the rows with weeks between 2016 W16 and 2016 W19 that are not represented in `df`. Here's what I mean:

```
df_result 
    Name      value      binary
    apple     2016 W16   1
    orange    2016 W16   0
    orange    2016 W17   1
    melon     2016 W16   0
    melon     2016 W17   0
    melon     2016 W18   0
    melon     2016 W19   0
    melon     2016 W20   1
    berry     2016 W17   1
    lime      2016 W19   1
    ...
```

But since `value` isn't a traditional date time object, I'm not sure how to get python to recognize that 2016 W16 occurs before 2016 W17, and then to only in-fill the values *before* the week stated in `value` in `df`.

I am having trouble with where to start, so if someone could help me convert `value` to a date time object that would be great, and I can go from there. Any other insight appreciated.

I found this stack overflow question which is all I have so far: [Match rows in one Pandas dataframe to another based on three columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24738732/match-rows-in-one-pandas-dataframe-to-another-based-on-three-columns).

Comment: Does this help you get started? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17087314/get-date-from-week-number

Comment: Given that the string structure of your week value is sorted in order of higher significance, any lexicographical comparison will work (i.e. `"2016 W15" < "2016 W28"` evaluates to `True`). I'm not sure I understand what your exact problem is, tho. I'll have to re-read your question a few times...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need convert to date

```
import datetime
df.value.apply(lambda x : datetime.datetime.strptime(x + '-0', "%Y W%W-%w"))
Out[133]: 
0   2016-04-24
1   2016-05-01
2   2016-05-22
3   2016-05-01
4   2016-05-15
Name: value, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

without change the date I am going to use `reindex` with `groupby`

```
df1=df.groupby('Name')['binary','value'].apply(lambda x : x.set_index('value').\
           reindex(['2016 W16','2016 W17','2016 W18','2016 W19','2016 W20']))

df1.loc[df1.groupby(level=0).binary.bfill().dropna().index].fillna(0).reset_index()
Out[65]: 
      Name     value  binary
0    apple  2016 W16     1.0
1    berry  2016 W16     0.0
2    berry  2016 W17     1.0
3     lime  2016 W16     0.0
4     lime  2016 W17     0.0
5     lime  2016 W18     0.0
6     lime  2016 W19     1.0
7    melon  2016 W16     0.0
8    melon  2016 W17     0.0
9    melon  2016 W18     0.0
10   melon  2016 W19     0.0
11   melon  2016 W20     1.0
12  orange  2016 W16     0.0
13  orange  2016 W17     1.0
```

Comment: I'm getting the error `ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis`. Do you know what that's from?

Comment: @JAG2024 check your `start_end_weeks`, does it have duplicate ?

Comment: There are only duplicate values in the `value` column of `df`.

Comment: The actual values in `reindex(['2016...` not linear. Like they jump from `2016 W 19` to `2016 W 25` if that makes a difference. @Wen

Comment: @JAG2024 if my second part does work for you , you can using the first part convert it to the datetime

Comment: Thanks @Wen. I got it to mostly work. I will post a new question for the part I can not get to work.

Comment: Perhaps you can help with the next version of this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47699464/reindex-pandas-dataframe-based-on-uneven-dates-and-then-groupby-and-blank-fill-c @Wen

Answer (score 2):

You can get a valid datetime date as follows:

```
from datetime import datetime

df['year'] = df.value.str.split(' W').str[0]
df['week'] = df.value.str.split(' W').str[1]
df['date'] = df.apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(
    x.year + '-' + x.week + '-0', '%Y-%W-%w'), axis=1)
```

And the result will be:

```
    Name    value  binary   year    week    date
0   apple   2016 W16    1   2016    16      2016-04-24
1   orange  2016 W17    1   2016    17      2016-05-01
2   melon   2016 W20    1   2016    20      2016-05-22
3   berry   2016 W17    1   2016    17      2016-05-01
4   lime    2016 W19    1   2016    19      2016-05-15
```